# Is there any dua that I can use so that I can be asked in my own language in the grave?

Tags: dua, day-of-judgement

I was born in Romania and I'm half Romanian and half Arab. I went to Kuwait and I stayed for 12 years. I used to know Arabic well, but now I forgot how to write and speak. I barely understand Arabic since we moved to my homeland (Romania), and I learned well my mother's language because it is my mother's language and it is a shame for me to not know how to speak correctly and to write. I wonder if there is any dua that I can use so that I'll be asked in the grave, like:

1. Cine e Stăpânul tău? — Dumnezeu e stăpânul meu.
2. Ce spui despre aceea persoana care a fost trimis printr voi? — Muhamed este profetul lui Dumnezeu
3. Care e religia ta? — Religia mea este Islam.

Because if I'll be asked in Arabic, I'll be asked in a much more academic Arabic, then I'll be shocked because I don't know how to answer their questions. If they were to ask me in my mother language, then yes I would answer correctly. So is there any dua as I mentioned here on text?

If there's any mistake there in text, please let me know so that I can edit it.

Comment: No, there is no such du'a in the Qur'an/Sunnah. But do not worry, dear brother, because there will be no language barrier in the Akhirah, including when you are being questioned by the Angels. Either the Angels will speak your language or you will be made to understand the language in which they speak.

Comment: Creating a new username seems a good workaround to bypass suspension.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Wait a second. How do you know I have changed the account??

Comment: Does it matters? Everybody has his signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such supplication for the following reasons:

- There is no account from the Prophet ﷺ or of any his companions of a supplication requesting a specific language to be used with them in the Hereafter.
- There is no authentic hadith that tells what the language of the questioning will be.

[Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah) was asked about the language used in the Hereafter (Majmū' al-Fatāwa, Vol. 4, pp. 300-301). He responded that the language of the Hereafter is not known because there is neither a verse in the Qur'an nor an authentic hadith that inform us thus. He added that the companions all from discussing the language of the Hereafter as that would have been mere speculation.

Some people claimed that the language is [Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic), others said people will be asked in [Syriac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_language), but the majority of scholars say that all such arguments lack textual evidence. Hence, the scholarly view is that we will communicate in a language that we will all master.

There is no need to worry, and no need for such a supplication.

[image: Majmū' al-Fatāwa, Vol. 4, pp. 300-301]

Comment: It would be nice if you would translate this from Arabic to English.

Comment: I have translated the main points under the paragraph starting with Ibn Taymiyyah.

Comment: One question, if I do for example many small haram thing which probably means that I did not followed prophet Muhammad’s teachings will this makes me not be able to answer the “Grave Questions” because I heard from someone about this and it sounds really scary. Like for example, if I repeat the same question and answer of “Grave Questions” even if I did many haram things, will I be able to answer in the Grave?

Comment: I have no knowledge of this. Please post a new question so that it may be addressed by a larger user base.

Comment: I wish I could, but I got a ban message.

Comment: Can you tell exactly, how many reputations I need to get rid of ban message?

Comment: @AlexA  — Such questions about reputation points are best addressed by doing a search in SE. Start [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/). If you are still unclear, post a question on [meta].